# MySQL Database design advice - using joins

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema

I am building an AJAX like search page which allows a customer to select a number filters that will narrow down the search. For instance, a user has selected an 'iPhone 5' and has additional filters for capacity (32GB, 64GB) & colour (black, white..).

The user can only select a single radio box per category (so they could select 32GB & Black).. but they could not select (32GB & 64GB & black as two of these belong to the 'capacity' category).

I have added the schema here on sqlfiddle (please ignore the fact i've removed the primary keys they exist in the proper app they have just been removed along with some other fields/data to minimise the sqlfiddle)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/964425

Can anyone suggest the best way to create the query to do the following:

```
Get all the prices for device_id '2939' (iPhone 5) which has the 'attributes' of '32GB' AND 'Black'
```

I currently have this - but this only works when selecting for a single attribute:

```
// search for device with '64GB' & 'Black' attributes (this currently doesn't return any rows)
SELECT `prices`.*
FROM (`prices`)
LEFT JOIN `prices_attributes` ON `prices_attributes`.`price_id` = `prices`.`id`
WHERE `prices`.`device_id` =  '2939'
AND `attribute_option_id` =  '19'
AND `attribute_option_id` =  '47';

// search for device with '64GB' attribute only (this currently DOES return a row)
SELECT `prices`.*
FROM (`prices`)
LEFT JOIN `prices_attributes` ON `prices_attributes`.`price_id` = `prices`.`id`
WHERE `prices`.`device_id` =  '2939'
AND `attribute_option_id` =  '19';
```

Any advice on the database design would be appreciated too

Note: I was thinking to have a new column within the 'prices' table that has the matching attribute_ids serialised - would this be not good for optimisation however (e.g would it be slower than the current method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `attribute_option_id` is an atomic value, it cannot have two different values for the *same* row. So your `WHERE` clause cannot match any record:

```
SELECT `prices`.*
FROM (`prices`)
LEFT JOIN `prices_attributes` ON `prices_attributes`.`price_id` = `prices`.`id`
WHERE `prices`.`device_id` =  '2939'
AND `attribute_option_id` =  '19'   # Here for one row, attribute_option_id is either 19
AND `attribute_option_id` =  '47';  # of '47'. Cannot be the both
```

---

Instead of  JOIN, you could try a subquery if you feel that is more readable. I think MySQL allow that syntax:

```
SELECT `prices`.*
FROM `prices`
WHERE `prices`.`device_id` =  '2939'
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM prices_attributes
               WHERE price_id = `prices`.`id`
               AND attribute_option_id IN ('19', '47') )
```

I don't know how MySQL will optimize the above solution. An alternative would be:

```
SELECT `prices`.*
FROM `prices`
WHERE `prices`.`id` IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT `price_id`
       FROM prices_attributes
       WHERE attribute_option_id IN ('19', '47')
)
```

Comment: I can see the IN command is great way to simplify a query to replace many OR conditions, as I want to use in essence many AND conditions is there a similar IN command for MySQL that will do AND's rather than OR's? (hope that makes sense)

Essentially if a user selects '32GB' AND 'Black' it would only return the iPhone device in the query if it has BOTH '32GB' and 'Black' attribute (e.g don't return if it is a iPhone 32GB White)

Comment: Not really directly, as you want to check 2 different rows with the AND. You need to either join the attributes multiple times, once for each required attribute, or join against a subselect of the attributes which have the require attribute values, with a count and check that the count is the same as the number of required attribute values.

Comment: I see what you mean.. this might get tricky as the number of attributes will vary (e.g some phones won't have capacity and may just have colour)
I'll have a try doing the attributes multiple times and see how that works as you mentioned in the comment directly above this one.

Comment: I've not used this solution but purely as i've learned some valuable SQL tips - thanks

Comment: Out of interest what was the solution you uses?

Comment: Even though all the ideas were very useful I basically went up going a slightly different route of simply grabbing all the rows, & doing logic with arrays with the PHP function array_intersect() etc to minimise the number of calls to the database (I probably didn't explain that too well lol) - but i've definitely gained from the posts so I am very grateful for all your tips. :)

Comment: Multiple calls to SQL is generally slower than a single call and doing the checks within the database (there are exceptions). I would expect that with a decently indexed database, once the amount of data grows and you are potentially bringing back thousands of rows back to be processed in php your chosen method will slow down dramatically compared to either this method or the one I highlighted below which would only bring back the relevant rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the IN operator for the attribute_option_id and you set the values dynamically to the query; Also, using group_by you have only one row per price so in effect you get all the prices. Apart from this, the design is ok.

Here, I have made an example:

```
SELECT `prices`.*
FROM (`prices`)
LEFT JOIN `prices_attributes` ON `prices_attributes`.`price_id` = `prices`.`id`
WHERE `prices`.`device_id` =  '2939'
and `attribute_option_id` in ('19','47')
group by `prices`.`device_id`, `prices`.`price`;
```

Here, you can also add an order clause to order by price:

```
order by `prices`.`price` desc;
```

Another way to solve this would be to use a distinct on price, like this:

```
select distinct(prices.price)
from prices
where prices.device_id = 2939
and id in (select price_id from prices_attributes where attribute_option_id in (19,47));
```

Comment: that looks like one SWEET solution. Thank you!! Totally forget about using the IN command, i'll give that a shot shortly and let you know how I get on.. thanks again you gotta love stackoverflow sometimes!

Comment: If I read the requirements correctly then the issue here is that it is checking for devices that have attribute_option_id of 19 OR 47, rather than both. One way this could be solved in the final example would be by selecting the price_id and the count of records in the subselect, with a HAVING clause to check the count is 2 (or however many options have been selected), although this would fail should there be duplicate records on the prices_attributes table.

Comment: some great responses guys! I'm using the CodeIgniter framework so will try to use the ActiveRecord system for generating queries as much as possible - however if required I will just use custom queries and modify accordingly. Thanks again.

Comment: as stated by @Kickstart i'm trying to get it to return on BOTH rather than either option.

Answer (score 1):

Join against the devices_attributes_options table several times, once for each attribute the item **must** have

Something like this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM devices a
INNER JOIN prices b ON a.id = b.device_id
INNER JOIN prices_attributes c ON b.id = c.price_id
INNER JOIN devices_attributes_options d ON c.attribute_option_id = d.id AND d.attribute_value = '32GB'
INNER JOIN devices_attributes_options e ON c.attribute_option_id = e.id AND e.attribute_value = 'Black'
WHERE a.id = 2939
```

As to putting serialised details into a field, this is a really bad idea and would come back to bite you in the future!

Comment: thanks for that - i'll give both methods a go and see which matches my requirements the best - thanks again for the tips guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE device_id=2939 AND id IN (SELECT price_id FROM prices_attributes WHERE attribute_option_id IN (19,47));
```

Is it what you're looking for?

EDIT: sorry, didn't notice you're asking for query using joins